# Python 2.7 socket htons

Tags: python, sockets

I am currently looking into socket programming in python and I am experiencing some strange behavior with socket.htons() ... it appears to be flipping the bytes on every call.

I am implementing a simple ping script, as far as I am aware network byte order is big endian and my systems byte order is little endian .

If I use htons on my 16 bit checksum wireshark reports that it is incorrect , however if I just pack the checksum into a struct without using htons wireshark confirms it is correct.

This is what wireshark has captured when using htons

```
Checksum: 0xece4 [incorrect, should be 0xe4ec]
```

And here is a quick example...

```
>>> z = 0xFF00
>>> print z
65280
>>> z = socket.htons(z)
>>> print z
255
>>> z = socket.htons(z)
>>> print z
65280
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated, hopefully its just me doing something very wrong.

Edit:

```
>>> print sys.byteorder
little
```

Comment: Can you include the output of: `print sys.byteorder` just to double check the endian?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your example. Each call to `htons()` is going to flip the bytes of the argument passed to it. It's stateless, after all, there's nothing in the data itself that says "I'm big endian" or "I'm little endian".

Comment: I thought the example was a little sketchy. In the docs for htons it says.. "On machines where the host byte order is the same as network byte order, this is a no-op;"  so a call to htons should always give me the checksum with the correct byte order regardless of the byte order of my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks to be working like it should.  Even in your example, the 2 bytes are being swapped, then back again.  If the system byte order is the same as the network, then its a no-op, but your question states that the network bytes order is *Big*, and the host is *Little*, so the swapping is what it should be doing.

```
In [1]: a = 0xECE4
In [2]: b = 0xE4EC

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 60644

In [4]: b
Out[4]: 58604

In [5]: socket.htons(a)
Out[5]: 58604

In [6]: socket.htons(b)
Out[6]: 60644

In [7]: socket.htons(a) == b
Out[7]: True

In [8]: socket.htons(b) == a
Out[8]: True

In [9]: hex(socket.htons(a))
Out[9]: '0xe4ec'

In [10]: hex(socket.htons(b))
Out[10]: '0xece4'

In [11]: bin(socket.htons(a))
Out[11]: '0b1110010011101100'

In [12]: bin(socket.htons(b))
Out[12]: '0b1110110011100100'
```

---

From the python [socket reference](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html):

> `socket.htons(x)`
>   Convert 16-bit positive integers from host to network
>   byte order. *On machines where the host byte order is the same as
>   network byte order, this is a **no-op***; otherwise, it performs a **2-byte
>   swap** operation.

Comment: Thanks, this has cleared up my misconception of how htons works. Which indicates the problem is actually in my checksum code. Thanks =]

Comment: @DarkRyuu: *Always* check *your* code first. Don't assume bugs on third party code, especially when it's about well-tested system libraries.